# Often 2 variants of feminine instrumental...?

Tags: местоимения, терминология, composite-nouns

maybe my title needs some work... but I use Wiktionary a lot for declensions, etc and I often see two forms for feminine instrumental adjectives, but my textbook only ever uses, typically, the 'first' one...

For example, https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9 for который, or for какой.

```
который -> fem. instr. -> кото́рой, кото́рою
какой -> fem. instr. -> како́й, како́ю
```

The same problem for me exists with singular instrumental for nouns like книга - https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0#Russian

```
какой ->  sing. instr. -> кни́гой, кни́гою
```

**Why are there two forms in these and many other words? What is the reason? When is each used?**

Comment: Will you please ask a question?

Comment: I can't find any rule for this, so my humble comment is: they are both valid and mean the same, but -ою forms sound old-fashioned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `-ою`/`-ею` forms are older and sound archaic/poetic. `-ой`/`-ей` is the modern form, reflecting the same trend towards loss of semantically weak final vowels that turned `-ти` infinitives into `-ть`.

With the exception of **ею**, the instrumental of the pronoun **она** which *some* prescribe as the preferred literary norm since **ей** is easily confused with the dative form, no `-ою`/`-ею` form is ever mandatory or preferred; in fact, unless there's a clear intent at mimicking an older literary style, these forms should probably be avoided. And even in actual older texts, you'll likely find them in free variation with `-ой`/`-ей`.

Answer (score 7):

The usual ending of feminine adjectives in the instrumental is -ой or -ей.

> Летом мы лакомились **вкусной** ягодой.
>   Вода была горячей-прегорячей.

Feminine adjectives can have the ending -ою,-ею in the instrumental case.(вариантные окончания). They are usef mainly in poetry, folklore or bookish style.

> Берёзы **жёлтою** резьбой
>
> Блестят в лазури голубой.
>
> И. Бунин.
>
> Под **сосною зеленою** спать положите вы меня.( Песня «Калинка»).

Sometimes the noun also uses the same poetic ending.