# Feminine instrumental -ою

Tags: склонение

Is the feminine instrumental in **-ою** literary only nowadays?

Comment: What a funny incident!

Comment: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/15256/often-2-variants-of-feminine-instrumental

Answer (score 1):

It isn't only literary, you can hear it in colloquial speech and rustic dialect, and in phraseology and idioms. Or just  to express you feelings brighter.

For example: "Я горжусь тоб**ой**" (I proud  of you) - is just regular phrase, means exactly what it means.

But "Я горжусь тоб**ою**!" - has a lot of feelings inside, mostly warm.

Comment: How does it express feelings more brightly?